# Cleaner way to copy a slice from one slightly-differently-named Multiindex to another

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to assign a slice of dfB to dfA.   Each df has multiindex columns where the level=0 has different names,  while the level=1 has same names between dataframe.

A simple copy of the slice doesn't work because the multindexes are not identical.

I have a gross hack to temporarily rename the slice (which is a Series) before it's assigned to the dataframe.  But this is gross. Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I am not able to rename the level=0 of either dataframe.

```
af = pd.DataFrame(index=range(4),columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['mike'], ['age', 'weight']]))
bf = pd.DataFrame(index=range(4),columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo'], ['age', 'weight']]))
for i in range(4):
    bf.loc[i,idx['foo','age']]= 10*i
    bf.loc[i,idx['foo', 'weight']]= "huge"
    
af.loc[1, idx['mike', 'age']] = bf.loc[1, idx['foo', 'age']]     # slice returns an int
af.loc[3, idx['mike', :]] = bf.loc[1, idx['foo', :]]             # slice returns a series

print("3 is not copied")
print(af)  # nothing copied to 3


#nasty hack.  Can I do better?
gross = af.loc[3, idx['mike', :]].index
hack = bf.loc[1, idx['foo', :]].copy()
hack.index = gross

af.loc[3, idx['mike', :]] = hack

print("\n3 IS copied")
print(af)
```

[image: asdf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For same indices use `rename`:

```
print (bf.loc[1, idx['foo', :]].rename({'foo':'mike'}, level=0))
mike  age         10
      weight    huge
Name: 1, dtype: object

af.loc[3, idx['mike', :]] = bf.loc[1, idx['foo', :]].rename({'foo':'mike'}, level=0)
print(af)
  mike       
   age weight
0  NaN    NaN
1  NaN    NaN
2  NaN    NaN
3   10   huge
```

Or assign numpy array:

```
af.loc[3, idx['mike', :]] = bf.loc[1, idx['foo', :]].to_numpy()
print(af)
  mike       
   age weight
0  NaN    NaN
1  NaN    NaN
2  NaN    NaN
3   10   huge
```